# Date order in bokeh plot with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 different scores per day:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame( {u'Date' : ['2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-20',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-20',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-20',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18', '2014-08-19', '2014-08-20'],
                    u'Score': [-0.13, -0.25, 0.1, -0.3, -0.1, 0.1,
                               -0.1, 0.1, -0.05, 0.2, -0.13, -0.25,
                               0.2, 0.5, 0.4, -0.2, -0.25, 0.1,
                               -0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05, -0.05, 0.2]})
    df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to plot the daily average of the score. I'm trying with:

```
from numpy import *
from bokeh.plotting import *
output_file('question.html')
figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=800, plot_height=500)
grouped = df.groupby("Date")
score = grouped["Score"]
avg = score.mean()
print dates
dates = asarray(grouped.groups.keys())
hold(True)
line(dates, avg, line_color="grey", line_width=8, line_join="round")
asterisk(dates, avg, line_color="black", size=15)
hold(False)
```

However, this code leads to a disordered dates array:

```
print dates
['2014-08-15T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2014-08-16T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2014-08-18T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2014-08-19T02:00:00.000000000+0200'
 '2014-08-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2014-08-20T02:00:00.000000000+0200']
```

and the line in the plot I obtain (see the image in [this link](http://siteforplot.weebly.com/)) is accordingly wrong.

Sortering by date with:

```
df = df.sort(['Date'])
```

does not helps.

On the other hand, if I try to plot the same dataframe but of 4 days instead of 6:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {u'Date' : ['2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18',
                               '2014-08-15', '2014-08-16', '2014-08-17', '2014-08-18'],
                    u'Score': [-0.13, -0.25, 0.1, -0.3,
                               -0.1, 0.1, -0.05, 0.2,
                               0.2, 0.5, 0.4, -0.2,
                               -0.3, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05]})
```

then the dates array is in order and the plot is correct. I don't understand why, but anyway what I want is the plot with 6 or more dates.

I would appreciate if you could please help me. It is clear that I am doing something wrong but I am a beginner in these languages and I have already tried hundreths of solutions, unsuccesfully. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the types:

```
>>> type(df.groupby('Date').groups)
<class 'dict'>
```

therefore, as a dictionary, `df.groupby('Date').groups` does not provide any *order guarantee* when you access items or keys; in your example `grouped.groups.keys()`; So you will lose consistency and correspondence between `dates` and `avg` when you pull them out of `groupby` separately.

If you want to work with `datetime` objects and simple numpy arrays (as opposed to the pandas series), you may do as below, in order to have the orders consistent:

```
>>> ts = df.groupby('Date')['Score'].mean()
>>> avg, dates = ts.values, ts.index.map(pd.Timestamp.date)
```

so you will have:

```
>>> avg
array([-0.0825,  0.1125,  0.175 , -0.0625, -0.1325,  0.0375])
>>> dates
array([datetime.date(2014, 8, 15), datetime.date(2014, 8, 16), datetime.date(2014, 8, 17), datetime.date(2014, 8, 18),
       datetime.date(2014, 8, 19), datetime.date(2014, 8, 20)], dtype=object)
```

Note that [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) has a default parameter `sort=True`, so the output is already sorted by index:

```
>>> df.groupby('Date')['Score'].mean()
Date
2014-08-15   -0.082
2014-08-16    0.112
2014-08-17    0.175
2014-08-18   -0.062
2014-08-19   -0.133
2014-08-20    0.038
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

The `avg` series will have the timestamps in the right order as the index, and can be passed directly to the bokeh plotting functions, like this.

```
line(avg.index, avg, line_color="grey", line_width=8, line_join="round")
asterisk(avg.index, avg, line_color="black", size=15)
```